# Building libcurl for Android versions lower than 6.0 (API level 23) fails

Tags: android, curl, android-ndk, libcurl

I'm attempting to build libcurl for Android using Clang on Windows but I'm facing a linker problem when building for Android API levels lower than 23 (Android 6.0). The linker complains that it cannot resolve symbols and spits out the following output:

```
undefined reference to 'stdin'
undefined reference to 'stdout'
undefined reference to 'stdin'
undefined reference to 'stdout'
undefined reference to 'stdout'
undefined reference to 'stderr'
undefined reference to 'stdout'
undefined reference to 'stdin'
undefined reference to 'stderr'
```

Behind the scenes I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with the "Mobile development with C++" workload to build libcurl. However, this should actually not really matter because Visual Studio eventually just invokes the tools provided by the Android NDK r16b. All commands that are invoked by Visual Studio are clearly visible.

The linker command that is used looks as follows (formatted for better readability):

```
C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe
-fdiagnostics-format=msvc
-o"obj\Debug\ARM\libcurl.so"
-Wl,-soname="libcurl.so"
-Wl,-rpath-link="C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\platforms\android-15\arch-arm\usr\lib"
-Wl,-L"C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\platforms\android-15\arch-arm\usr\lib"
-Wl,-L"C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\4.9.x\armv7-a"
-Wl,-L"C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs\armeabi-v7a"
-Wl,--no-undefined
-gcc-toolchain "C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64"
-target "armv7-none-linux-androideabi"
--sysroot="C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\platforms\android-15\arch-arm"
-Wl,-z,relro
-Wl,-z,now
-Wl,-z,noexecstack
-shared obj\Debug\ARM\cleartext.o
obj\Debug\ARM\cram.o
obj\Debug\ARM\digest.o
obj\Debug\ARM\digest_sspi.o
obj\Debug\ARM\krb5_gssapi.o
obj\Debug\ARM\krb5_sspi.o
obj\Debug\ARM\ntlm.o
obj\Debug\ARM\ntlm_sspi.o
obj\Debug\ARM\oauth2.o
obj\Debug\ARM\spnego_gssapi.o
obj\Debug\ARM\spnego_sspi.o
obj\Debug\ARM\vauth.o
obj\Debug\ARM\cyassl.o
obj\Debug\ARM\gskit.o
obj\Debug\ARM\gtls.o
obj\Debug\ARM\mbedtls.o
obj\Debug\ARM\mesalink.o
obj\Debug\ARM\nss.o
obj\Debug\ARM\openssl.o
obj\Debug\ARM\polarssl.o
obj\Debug\ARM\polarssl_threadlock.o
obj\Debug\ARM\schannel.o
obj\Debug\ARM\schannel_verify.o
obj\Debug\ARM\sectransp.o
obj\Debug\ARM\vtls.o
obj\Debug\ARM\altsvc.o
obj\Debug\ARM\amigaos.o
obj\Debug\ARM\asyn-ares.o
obj\Debug\ARM\asyn-thread.o
obj\Debug\ARM\base64.o
obj\Debug\ARM\conncache.o
obj\Debug\ARM\connect.o
obj\Debug\ARM\content_encoding.o
obj\Debug\ARM\cookie.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_addrinfo.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_ctype.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_des.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_endian.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_fnmatch.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_get_line.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_gethostname.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_gssapi.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_memrchr.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_multibyte.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_ntlm_core.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_ntlm_wb.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_path.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_range.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_rtmp.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_sasl.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_sspi.o
obj\Debug\ARM\curl_threads.o
obj\Debug\ARM\dict.o
obj\Debug\ARM\doh.o
obj\Debug\ARM\dotdot.o
obj\Debug\ARM\easy.o
obj\Debug\ARM\escape.o
obj\Debug\ARM\file.o
obj\Debug\ARM\fileinfo.o
obj\Debug\ARM\formdata.o
obj\Debug\ARM\ftp.o
obj\Debug\ARM\ftplistparser.o
obj\Debug\ARM\getenv.o
obj\Debug\ARM\getinfo.o
obj\Debug\ARM\gopher.o
obj\Debug\ARM\hash.o
obj\Debug\ARM\hmac.o
obj\Debug\ARM\hostasyn.o
obj\Debug\ARM\hostcheck.o
obj\Debug\ARM\hostip.o
obj\Debug\ARM\hostip4.o
obj\Debug\ARM\hostip6.o
obj\Debug\ARM\hostsyn.o
obj\Debug\ARM\http.o
obj\Debug\ARM\http_chunks.o
obj\Debug\ARM\http_digest.o
obj\Debug\ARM\http_negotiate.o
obj\Debug\ARM\http_ntlm.o
obj\Debug\ARM\http_proxy.o
obj\Debug\ARM\http2.o
obj\Debug\ARM\idn_win32.o
obj\Debug\ARM\if2ip.o
obj\Debug\ARM\imap.o
obj\Debug\ARM\inet_ntop.o
obj\Debug\ARM\inet_pton.o
obj\Debug\ARM\krb5.o
obj\Debug\ARM\ldap.o
obj\Debug\ARM\llist.o
obj\Debug\ARM\md4.o
obj\Debug\ARM\md5.o
obj\Debug\ARM\memdebug.o
obj\Debug\ARM\mime.o
obj\Debug\ARM\mprintf.o
obj\Debug\ARM\multi.o
obj\Debug\ARM\netrc.o
obj\Debug\ARM\non-ascii.o
obj\Debug\ARM\nonblock.o
obj\Debug\ARM\nwlib.o
obj\Debug\ARM\nwos.o
obj\Debug\ARM\openldap.o
obj\Debug\ARM\parsedate.o
obj\Debug\ARM\pingpong.o
obj\Debug\ARM\pop3.o
obj\Debug\ARM\progress.o
obj\Debug\ARM\psl.o
obj\Debug\ARM\rand.o
obj\Debug\ARM\rtsp.o
obj\Debug\ARM\security.o
obj\Debug\ARM\select.o
obj\Debug\ARM\sendf.o
obj\Debug\ARM\setopt.o
obj\Debug\ARM\sha256.o
obj\Debug\ARM\share.o
obj\Debug\ARM\slist.o
obj\Debug\ARM\smb.o
obj\Debug\ARM\smtp.o
obj\Debug\ARM\socks.o
obj\Debug\ARM\socks_gssapi.o
obj\Debug\ARM\socks_sspi.o
obj\Debug\ARM\speedcheck.o
obj\Debug\ARM\splay.o
obj\Debug\ARM\ssh.o
obj\Debug\ARM\ssh-libssh.o
obj\Debug\ARM\strcase.o
obj\Debug\ARM\strdup.o
obj\Debug\ARM\strerror.o
obj\Debug\ARM\strtok.o
obj\Debug\ARM\strtoofft.o
obj\Debug\ARM\system_win32.o
obj\Debug\ARM\telnet.o
obj\Debug\ARM\tftp.o
obj\Debug\ARM\timeval.o
obj\Debug\ARM\transfer.o
obj\Debug\ARM\url.o
obj\Debug\ARM\urlapi.o
obj\Debug\ARM\version.o
obj\Debug\ARM\warnless.o
obj\Debug\ARM\wildcard.o
obj\Debug\ARM\x509asn1.o
-landroid_support
-lc++_shared
-lc++abi
-llog
-landroid
```

The object files that are linked by the above command are all compiled using the same Clang switches. An example looks as follows:

```
C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe
-c
-fdiagnostics-format=msvc
-gcc-toolchain "C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64"
-target "armv7-none-linux-androideabi"
--sysroot="C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\sysroot"
-isystem "C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\sysroot\usr\include\arm-linux-androideabi"
-I "C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include"
-I "C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++abi\include"
-I "C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\sysroot\usr\include"
-I "C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\sysroot\usr\include\arm-linux-androideabi"
-I "C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\sources\android\support\include"
-I D:\MyProject\libcurl_src\
-I D:\MyProject\libcurl_src\curl\lib
-I D:\MyProject\libcurl_src\curl\include
-I "C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include"
-g2
-gdwarf-2
-o "obj\Debug\ARM\altsvc.o"
-Wall
-O0
-fno-strict-aliasing
-mthumb
-fno-omit-frame-pointer
-fexceptions
-mfloat-abi=softfp
-fstack-protector
-fpic
-fno-short-enums
-D HAVE_CONFIG_H
-x c D:\MyProject\libcurl_src\curl\lib\altsvc.c
```

As soon as I change the paths provided to the linker from `\android-15\` to `\android-23\` it links successfully. However, I need to support Android versions earlier than 6.0 so this does not resolve the issue.

The `curl_config.h` file that I'm using looks as follows:

```
#define BUILDING_LIBCURL 1
#define CURL_STATICLIB 1
#if defined(__ANDROID__)
#define CURL_CA_PATH "/system/etc/security/cacerts"
#endif
#define CURL_DISABLE_DICT 1
#define CURL_DISABLE_FILE 1
#define CURL_DISABLE_FTP 1
#define CURL_DISABLE_GOPHER 1
#define CURL_DISABLE_IMAP 1
#define CURL_DISABLE_LDAP 1
#define CURL_DISABLE_LDAPS 1
#define CURL_DISABLE_POP3 1
#define CURL_DISABLE_RTSP 1
#define CURL_DISABLE_SMB 1
#define CURL_DISABLE_SMTP 1
#define CURL_DISABLE_TELNET 1
#define CURL_DISABLE_TFTP 1
#define CURL_EXTERN_SYMBOL __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define CURL_SA_FAMILY_T sa_family_t
#define ENABLE_IPV6 1
#define GETHOSTNAME_TYPE_ARG2 size_t
#define HAVE_ALARM 1
#define HAVE_ALLOCA_H 1
#define HAVE_ARPA_INET_H 1
#define HAVE_ARPA_TFTP_H 1
#define HAVE_ASSERT_H 1
#define HAVE_BASENAME 1
#define HAVE_BOOL_T 1
#define HAVE_BUILTIN_AVAILABLE 1
#define HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME_MONOTONIC 1
#define HAVE_CONNECT 1
#define HAVE_DECL_GETPWUID_R 1
#define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
#define HAVE_ERRNO_H 1
#define HAVE_ERR_H 1
#define HAVE_FCNTL 1
#define HAVE_FCNTL_H 1
#define HAVE_FCNTL_O_NONBLOCK 1
#define HAVE_FNMATCH 1
#define HAVE_FREEADDRINFO 1
#define HAVE_FSETXATTR 1
#define HAVE_FSETXATTR_5 1
#define HAVE_FTRUNCATE 1
#define HAVE_GAI_STRERROR 1
#define HAVE_GETADDRINFO 1
#define HAVE_GETADDRINFO_THREADSAFE 1
#define HAVE_GETEUID 1
#define HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR 1
#define HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R 1
#define HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_8 1
#define HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME 1
#define HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R 1
#define HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6 1
#define HAVE_GETHOSTNAME 1
#define HAVE_GETPEERNAME 1
#define HAVE_GETPPID 1
#define HAVE_GETPWUID 1
#define HAVE_GETPWUID_R 1
#define HAVE_GETRLIMIT 1
#define HAVE_GETSOCKNAME 1
#define HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY 1
#define HAVE_GMTIME_R 1
#define HAVE_IFADDRS_H 1
#define HAVE_IF_NAMETOINDEX 1
#define HAVE_INET_NTOP 1
#define HAVE_INET_PTON 1
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_IOCTL 1
#define HAVE_IOCTL_FIONBIO 1
#define HAVE_IOCTL_SIOCGIFADDR 1
#define HAVE_LIBGEN_H 1
#define HAVE_LIBSSL 1
#if defined(__ANDROID__)
#define HAVE_LINUX_TCP_H 1
#endif
#define HAVE_LL 1
#define HAVE_LOCALE_H 1
#define HAVE_LOCALTIME_R 1
#define HAVE_LONGLONG 1
#define HAVE_MALLOC_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#if defined(__ANDROID__)
#define HAVE_MEMRCHR 1
#endif
#if defined(__ANDROID__)
#define HAVE_MSG_NOSIGNAL 1
#endif
#define HAVE_NETDB_H 1
#define HAVE_NETINET_IN_H 1
#define HAVE_NETINET_TCP_H 1
#define HAVE_NET_IF_H 1
#define HAVE_PIPE 1
#define HAVE_POLL 1
#define HAVE_POLL_FINE 1
#define HAVE_POLL_H 1
#define HAVE_POSIX_STRERROR_R 1
#define HAVE_PTHREAD_H 1
#define HAVE_PWD_H 1
#define HAVE_RECV 1
#define HAVE_SELECT 1
#define HAVE_SEND 1
#define HAVE_SETJMP_H 1
#define HAVE_SETLOCALE 1
#define HAVE_SETRLIMIT 1
#define HAVE_SETSOCKOPT 1
#define HAVE_SIGACTION 1
#define HAVE_SIGINTERRUPT 1
#define HAVE_SIGNAL 1
#define HAVE_SIGNAL_H 1
#define HAVE_SIG_ATOMIC_T 1
#define HAVE_SOCKADDR_IN6_SIN6_SCOPE_ID 1
#define HAVE_SOCKET 1
#define HAVE_SOCKETPAIR 1
#define HAVE_STDBOOL_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRCASECMP 1
#define HAVE_STRDUP 1
#define HAVE_STRERROR_R 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_STRNCASECMP 1
#define HAVE_STRSTR 1
#define HAVE_STRTOK_R 1
#define HAVE_STRTOLL 1
#define HAVE_STRUCT_SOCKADDR_STORAGE 1
#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMEVAL 1
#define HAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_PARAM_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_POLL_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_RESOURCE_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TIME_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_UIO_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_UN_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_WAIT_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_XATTR_H 1
#define HAVE_TERMIOS_H 1
#define HAVE_TERMIO_H 1
#define HAVE_TIME_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define HAVE_UTIME 1
#define HAVE_UTIMES 1
#define HAVE_UTIME_H 1
#define HAVE_VARIADIC_MACROS_C99 1
#define HAVE_VARIADIC_MACROS_GCC 1
#define HAVE_WRITEV 1
#define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
#define OS "arm-unknown-linux-android"
#define PACKAGE "curl"
#define PACKAGE_NAME "curl"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "curl -"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "curl"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "-"
#define RECV_TYPE_ARG1 int
#define RECV_TYPE_ARG2 void *
#define RECV_TYPE_ARG3 size_t
#define RECV_TYPE_ARG4 int
#define RECV_TYPE_RETV ssize_t
#define RETSIGTYPE void
#define SELECT_QUAL_ARG5 
#define SELECT_TYPE_ARG1 int
#define SELECT_TYPE_ARG234 fd_set *
#define SELECT_TYPE_ARG5 struct timeval *
#define SELECT_TYPE_RETV ssize_t
#define SEND_QUAL_ARG2 const
#define SEND_TYPE_ARG1 int
#define SEND_TYPE_ARG2 void *
#define SEND_TYPE_ARG3 size_t
#define SEND_TYPE_ARG4 int
#define SEND_TYPE_RETV ssize_t
#define SIZEOF_CURL_OFF_T 8
#define SIZEOF_INT 4
#define SIZEOF_LONG 4
#define SIZEOF_LONG_LONG 8
#define SIZEOF_OFF_T 4
#define SIZEOF_SHORT 2
#define SIZEOF_SIZE_T 4
#define SIZEOF_TIME_T 4
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define STRERROR_R_TYPE_ARG3 size_t
#define TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME 1
#if defined(__ANDROID__)
//#define USE_MBEDTLS 1
#endif
#if defined(_WIN32)
#define USE_SCHANNEL 1
#endif
#if defined(__APPLE__)
#define USE_SECTRANSP 1
#endif
#define USE_THREADS_POSIX 1
#define USE_UNIX_SOCKETS 1
#define VERSION "-"
#ifndef _ALL_SOURCE
#endif
#ifndef _DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE
# define _DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE 1
#endif
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

Does anyone have a hint why I might face this problem?

I'm not sure why libcurl would actually need `stdin` / `stdout` / `stderr` at all. It makes sense for the curl executable but maybe I'm lucky and can somehow strip out the corresponding functionality from libcurl. Any hints regarding this?

Comment: Have you tried to use `./configure`, like [here](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/d964444f4a85c2598053) ?

Comment: This looks like you compiled against an API level of 23+ and are linking against something lower. How did you configure, how did you build, and what does the compiler command line look like?

Comment: @AlexCohn: I actually tried that but the problem is that I'm building on Windows while those instructions are tailored for Linux. However, using the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" (provides a Linux environment on top of Windows 10) I could partially do those steps. To me it seems I have a valid `curl_config.h` that results from invoking `./configure`. The rest is just invoking a `make` file. However, I cannot use that step because I'm using Visual Studio to build libcurl.

Comment: @DanAlbert: I have modified my original question to include a compiler command that is used to generate the object files that get linked. Since I'm building on Windows I had real troubles with the configuration step. Eventually I used the `curl_config.h` file of Android (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/curl/+/refs/heads/master/lib/curl_config.h) as a template for my own version which I posted in the question.

Comment: After digging into this problem a bit more I came across the following: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-release-r16/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md. It clearly states that in order to use the GCC standalone toolchain it is necessary to specify `-D__ANDROID_API__=$API`. In my case that would be `-D__ANDROID_API__=15`. This indeed resolved the problem which would mean Microsoft's Android build process contains a bug. @DanAlbert: If you're the guy behind https://github.com/android-ndk you're probably the right guy to confirm whether this is the "right" way of solving the problem.

Comment: If it is, I'll open a bug with Microsoft.

Comment: I would recommend to build libcurl in WSL and use the library prebuilt in your project. This, at least, is how I prefer to deal with big and sophisticated 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @AlexCohn: I understand and this is generally good advice. The reason I'm attempting to build from source is that I'm building an app for three different platforms which means it is suddenly not that easy anymore to get the correct prebuilt version for each platform.

Comment: Yes, if you're using GCC you need to pass that flag. A better fix would be to switch to Clang though (and update to a newer NDK while you're at it so you can get a better C++ stdlib too).

Comment: When I speak of prebuilt, I don't mean downloading binaries from GitHub. What I suggest is that you prebuild libcurl for yourself.